# If no ciphers are enabled for TLSv1.0, can the negotiation still happen?

Tags: ssl, encryption, cryptography

If no ciphers are enabled for TLSv1.0, can the negotiation still happen? What behavior should SSL display?

Answer (score 1):

> If no ciphers are enabled for TLSv1.0, can the negotiation still happen?

No. It will send an alert: 'no cipher suites in common'.

> What behavior should SSL display?

SSL doesn't display anything.

Comment: Although the application could show or log 'no cipher suites in common' :P More seriously, I guess it depends what is part of the "negotiation", the negotiation will start but it will immediately end with the alert - sent by the server, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes That's correct, SSL alerts terminate the connection.

Comment: Something smells fishy with this question. Shouldn't the client start at TLS 1.2, then fallback to TLS 1.1, and then fallback to TLS 1.0? The OP likely will never get to his condition because TLS 1.2 will result in a connection.

Comment: @jww It's not clear exactly what he means. I assumed he means he is using TLSv1.0 with an empty cipher suite list.